# Why doesn't Google Places API return a business when given a lat/long like a regular Google Search does?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Ok so let's say for instance I'm trying to find the business that is returned from this google search (using the Google Places API):

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=precision+services+6632+warrior+river+road+bessemer+al+35023

Firstly I use the Google Geocoding API to get lat/long for the exact address of the business(6632 Warrior River Road, Bessemer, AL)

Then when I try to use the Place ID that is returned OR use a nearby search with that lat/long I am never able to get the business that is returned from the regular google search...

My goal is to get the business website using a business address but so far I can't reliably do that with Google Places API nearly as well as just doing a regular Google Search.

Is there something I am doing wrong and someway I can get the business to be returned or is that just the way it is?

As a side note I've tried using the parameters "keyword" and "name" with the business name pretty much everything I can think of and the business I am looking for is never returned whereas if I search it on google it is always in the box on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

There are (currently) issues geolocating "Service Area" Businesses (those that don't have a fixed address) with the Places API.

- [Issue 8986: Bug: Unable to find Place IDs for certain businesses](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8986)
- [Issue 8900: Places API Details and Search return NOT_FOUND for Service Area Business with valid Place ID](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8900)
- [Issue 35828187: Support service area businesses](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828187)

Comment: That's really strange seeing as when you google search it; google knows it's the most relevant and has it there on the right...Any way around this in the API or anyway to have it actually be returned by the API?

Comment: Google Search and the Places API are different things.  The Places API data is only one of the sources used by Google Search.