# Place ID showing "NOT FOUND" error for place details API - outdated place ID

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Trying to use Places API but the place ID is not valid. I have tried to use the nearby search but I keep coming up with Not Found error or invalid ID.

It is a service area business so I got the ID from inspecting the Write a Review for the GB profile.

This is the nearby search string I'm using (with exact lat/long) but it's not returning the searched business (it does return nearby businesses). Found this from [Place ID gives "NOT FOUND" error for place details API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477186/place-id-gives-not-found-error-for-place-details-api):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.944640,151.228100&key=API-KEY&rankby=distance&pagetoken=

A place ID is showing on Google but when I try to use it with my API, it says it needs to be refreshed in the cache.

I've tried the Google maps nearby search but I'm either not getting the URL string correct or it's just not working.

Name of company is: Key Solutions Locksmith (current - invalid - place ID: ChIJ4ZphJoX7c6kRcsTRFd-cd_Y)

This is the nearby search string I'm using (with exact lat/long) but it's not returning the searched business (it does return nearby businesses but they all seem to be storefront instead of service area.

Also tried: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=NUMBER%20STREETNAME%20Street,%20Maroubra,%202035&types=address&components=country:au&key=API-KEY

with just the address but the place ID it returned shows no reviews so it's not connected to the actual service area business.

How can I get a new (refresh) my place ID to get it to work with the Places API?

Thanks

Comment: related: [Why doesn't Google Places API return a business when given a lat/long like a regular Google Search does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150031/why-doesnt-google-places-api-return-a-business-when-given-a-lat-long-like-a-reg)

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828187